# conditional probability, logical product

Tags: probability

I was working my way through Kruschke's textbook and got to Chapter 9 and the result on factoring out conditional probabilities for hierarchical models, seemed similar to something in Feller Vol1 Chapter 5, but I'm not sure how to translate the notation.

In Kruscke's textbook it says
 $ p(\theta, \omega | D ) \propto p(D| \theta, \omega ) p(\theta , \omega)$
factors into $ = p(D| \theta ) p(\theta | \omega) p(\omega) $

In Feller's textbook there's a theorem that says 
$ P(AH) = P(A | H) *P$ and this result generalizes to P{ABC} = P(A|BC) * P(B|C) *P(C)

I understand the translation isn't perfect between the theorems but is the (something |a, b)the same thing as  (something | AB)

Looking at this example in Jayne's textbook I see that it might be the same thing cause it says here http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/prob/book.pdf on pg 10 it's a conjunction but i'm still unsure.

Question IS $ p(a|b,c) \text{ the same thing as }  p(a| BC) $ This sort of factoring of conditionals and such seems important to learn.

Comment: $\Pr[BC]=\Pr[B,C]=\Pr[B\cap C]=\Pr[B \land C]$ if $B$ and $C$ are events (and not random variables), i.e. $B=\{\omega: X(\omega)\text{ for some condition}\}$